# Supervised Classification: determining Training & Validation Data Sample Sizes

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, image-classification

How does one determine Training & Validation sample sizes for Supervised Classification?

My scenario: I'm using a previous year's classified map (2019) as an "a-priori" guide for picking training data for 2021 imagery. My question is how do I determine what my correct sample sizes for Training and Validation data?

I've looked on the web, and in my text book (Introductory Digital Image Processing), but no heuristics were found.

Here's my GEE code example for context (I added a legend for landcover classes):

- https://code.earthengine.google.com/9062e694aea72b7227b5e1d3b9d70582

---

Extra context: Here's the basic tutorial I initially followed (great stuff!)

- https://github.com/geospatialeco/GEARS/blob/master/Intro_RS_Lab4.md

Comment: Some author recommends training samples of minimum 5 to 10 polygons, others a total size of 100 pixels per class. There are several points of view and recommendations, therefore there isn't a strict rule. It also depends on your classification scheme. In the case of machine learning, sample sizes should be equal among classes, or the model will be biased.

Comment: Definitely useful overall info, but was looking for a practical answer. Like given that example code in the question, a scene at 30 meter resolution, if I were to be using a classification scheme like Random Forest, might there be a calculation for those sample sizes? Something with a confidence interval?

Comment: The word I hate the most: *depends*. As I said, there is no strict rule. It depends on the homogeneity of your data, the ML algorithm, the numbers of inputs (scenes used) and outputs (classes). Since you're using RF, the number of trees will also depend on your training size. What I normally do is: 1) draw AOIs by class. 2) extract pixel info. 3) check sample size by class. 4) random sample of pixels `smallest class size*0.7` for training and `smallest class size*0.3` for validation. 5) tune model with training. 6) test model with validation. 7) apply the final model to the whole set of data